# Add class to an element inside a directive with angular and without jquery

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple directive and I'd like to access one of its inner DOM element to add a class to it.

```
div(my-directive)
  div
    // some html
    span.myDiv
       | some text
```

My HTML has much more elements than this so accessing `.myDiv` via the `.childen()` method is quite tedious.

I've tried the following which doesn't work:

```
.directive('myDiv', ['$compile', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element) {
      var el = element[0].getElementsByClassName('myDiv')

      angular.element(el).addClass('myAwesomeClass')
      $compile(el)(scope)

    }
  }
}])
```

How can I do this?

Many thanks

Comment: ok, why would you need to do that? but if you do need to do some complex css selector operation i would advice to use something like sizzle. how ever 90% of the manipulation you would need to do to the DOMcan be done via data binding and templating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelector` to find the target element to add the class.
`$compile(el)(scope)` is not required here when you add a class using angular.

[JSBin Preview](http://jsbin.com/yaxewanuga/2/)

[JsBin Edit](http://jsbin.com/bucowabojo/1/edit)

Comment: you can use element[0].querySelector than you only search in the subtree under the directive